# Prevent infinite loop with self-referencial records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, join

I've got a model that has a self-referencial join through a join table, as defined below:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :dependency_dependents, foreign_key: :dependency_id, class_name: 'TaskDependency', dependent: :destroy
    has_many :dependency_dependencies, foreign_key: :task_id, class_name: 'TaskDependency', dependent: :destroy, autosave: true

    has_many :dependencies, through: :dependency_dependencies
    has_many :dependents, through: :dependency_dependents, source: :task
end

class TaskDependency < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :task
    belongs_to :dependency, class_name: 'Task'
end
```

Everything with the joins works well. When the record is saved, it performs a bunch of calculations based on the records it depends on, and it then moves on the updating the dependent records which in turn perform the same calculations for those records and so on.

The issue is that if somewhere in the chain of dependent tasks, there is a dependency on a task somewhere else up the tree, firstly the calculations will fail, but most importantly, it'll cause an infinite loop of calculations and updates.

Is there a nice way I can check for this infinite loop before I save a record, (ideally before creating the dependency in the first place).

I'm happy to do this either using pure SQL or ruby, just wondering if anyone has a clean solution for this.

Comment: Hm, cycle detection in an adjacency list. It can be done with a trigger, but you have to lock the table to ensure there are no concurrent inserts, otherwise the cycle could be created by two concurrent inserts that are each individually OK, but problematic together.

Comment: I've been playing around with a recursive query for postgres. Thinking if I list all dependencies before I insert the new one, and if it exists already somewhere in the chain don't save it. But you're still right about two concurrent inserts :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I think I've got it figured out. When the record validates, it calls a new validation method which runs a recursive query which pulls out all the ID's in the hierarchy below it, and if the ID of the task that you are trying to make a dependency is found in the list of dependents, then it fails validation. The query for this is below:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dependencies(task_id, path) AS (
  SELECT task_id, ARRAY[task_id]
  FROM task_dependencies
  WHERE dependency_id = #{self.id}

  UNION ALL

  SELECT task_dependencies.task_id, path || task_dependencies.task_id
  FROM dependencies
  JOIN task_dependencies ON dependencies.task_id = task_dependencies.dependency_id
  WHERE NOT task_dependencies.task_id = ANY(path)

)

SELECT task_id id FROM dependencies ORDER BY path
```

Never know, maybe this will help someone along the way.
As mentioned by @craig-ringer though, there is still the possibility of two concurrent inserts occurring leading to a race condition, but this query could also in turn lock the table to prevent this happening if necessary.